# PhpStorm code formatter and indentation

Tags: php, symfony, intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm with Symfony 3 to write my project.

But I've an issue. When I reformat the code,

This code :

[image]

Turns into this code :

[image]

And I don't know what is the setting I have to change to fix that :/ Any idea?

Comment: The indentation seems correct, if you need it differently just use tab.

Comment: Nothing to fix really, that is how method chaining is generally formatted, since there is no way to determine the level of each chained node. I tend not to reformat Symfony configuration files for that reason and the indentation is just for readability.

Comment: In addition to what @fyrye said -- you either do not format this file/code fragment .. or you may surround such code with "do not format me" comments - see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/code-style.html#d366576e184

Comment: @graille and please vote and comment for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-18803 request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for this at https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html

First enable formatter markers in `Settings`->`Editor`->`Tab:Formatter Control`

After that, you can switch on/off the formatter on every statement/docblock via

```
// @formatter:off
```

or

```
/**
 * @formatter:off
 */
```

be sure, that you enable the formatter with `// @formatter:on` if you want to format the code below your chained method call.

Answer (score 0):

You change it in  Menu:

`File` -> `Default Settings` -> `Editor` -> `Code Style` -> `PHP`
and overlap: `Wrapping and Braces`:

```
Chained method calls : "Wrap always"
  Align when multiline   "Y"
  Place ';' on new Line  "Y"
```

After it you can reformat yours code `CTR+ALT+L`

Comment: @graille Is it OK now?

Comment: Your suggestion causes the method operators to align vertically (opposite of what the OP wants). While forcing all chained method calls to be on a new line, and then places the `;` on its own line. The `OP` wants to preserve the indentation to visually represent the hierarchy of the Symfony Configuration, similar to how multi-dimensional arrays are displayed when multi-line.